# MVC 5 @actionLinq to Index() Error on server only

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, controller, windows-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's my problem in Asp.net mvc5:

I developed an application that allows users to connect Owin and then enter a dashboard with many functionality.

My dashboard uses actions located in several controllers by ActionLinq  "libel", "Action", "Controller"

Each action uses the same connection string (dbentities) in my Web.config

> Each of my actions are OK ...Details, Delete, Insert except Index() on SERVER ONLY
>   that returns: Error Error occured while processing your request (Debug
>   firefox: Error 500 internal server).

```
If I host application on my desktop IIS that's OK It Works ....
```

My Index page contains a table, I tried to removed the ajax calls, leaving only native functions.`

The Js libraries are loaded correctly and I did not use any library on the net.

I simplified my controller by removing the ViewModel, I always had error.

I host the application in a Windows Server 2008R2 DMZ (IIS7.5).
I tried to host the application on another server (VM off Dmz) and the error continues.

So the application return this error only if hosted in another server than my computeur.

The build does not return an error(no warning too), I also tried to host non compiled full application, it's the same thing.

On the database server, I have no record(trace) of my call controller Index() when my application is hosted on the server.
Conversely when I host application on my post, the call to the database server is OK for this feature.

```
VisualStudio ====> Index () =====> INSTANCE_Sql OK
VisualStudio ===========> Delete () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
VisualStudio ===========> CustomeActions ... () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
VisualStudio ===========> Insert () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK

MyComputeur IIS ====> Index () =====> INSTANCE_Sql OK
MyComputeur IIS ===========> Delete () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
MyComputeur IIS ===========> CustomeActions ... () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
MyComputeur IIS ===========> Insert () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK



IIS ON DMZ ===========> Index () ======> INSTANCE_Sql NOK
IIS ON DMZ ===========> Delete () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
IIS ON DMZ ===========> CustomeActions ... () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
IIS ON DMZ ===========> Insert () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK

 ===========> Index () ======> INSTANCE_Sql NOK

IIS SERVER ON OTHERSERVER ===========> Index () ======> INSTANCE_Sql NOK
IIS SERVER ON OTHERSERVER ===========> Delete () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
IIS SERVER ON OTHERSERVER ===========> CustomeActions ... () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
IIS SERVER ON OTHER ===========> Insert () ======> INSTANCE_Sql OK
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: So, what's the internal server error?

Comment: there is nothing on server no log, i just have this error on my browers Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Well, *somehow* you have to find out what's going wrong at the server. Maybe you explicitly return a 500 in your code without logging it?

Comment: Ok for you it's a server problem right .?  ill try to add this function without login in

Comment: Any idéa please ?